# MVC vb: Intellisense not working on imports statement (VS2012)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, razor, intellisense

I'm trying to develop an mvc 4 project using VB.
I noticed that in view files (vbhtml) I dont get any intellisense just in the @Imports statement while instead everything works fine in projects developed in c#.

I already tried to reset all the environment settings but without success.

Anyone experiencing the same issue?

Comment: I haven't tried C#, but I'm definitely having issues in VB with intellisense and the `@Imports` statement.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29830300/cannot-use-imports-in-vbhtml-file